# Creating Vector in R (multiple conditions)

Tags: r

Need to create and print a vector in R that includes the following in this order:

- A sequence of integers from 6 to 10 (inclusive)
- A twofold repetition of the vector c(2, -5.1, -33)
- The value of the sum of 7/42 and 2

a) Then extract the first and last elements of the vector to form another vector
b) Form a third vector from the elements not extracted above
* Use the vectors from (a) and (b) to reconstruct and print the original first vector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should do it:

> a.vec<-c(seq(6,10,1),rep(c(2,-5.1,-33),times=2),(7/42+2))
>
> b.vec<-a.vec[c(1,length(a.vec))]
>
> c.vec<-a.vec[-c(1,length(a.vec))]
>
> a.vec<-c(b.vec[1],c.vec,b.vec[2])